# Is Opencart token on url the session id?

Tags: php, url, get, opencart, access-token

In opencart I see that URLs look like this below:

> https://www.example.com/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=Ger45ZJMsdfSSDggHfghI4wcQzbD

is this token my session id? If yes, is it secure to pass session id on url (with or without ssl)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `token` parameter is not the session id.

The `token` parameter is assigned as a session variable by `admin/controller/common/login.php` when you log in (varies depending on version):

```
$this->session->data['token'] = md5(mt_rand());
```

To get the session id you can call:

```
$this->session->getId();
```

Which is defined in `system/library/session.php`.  You can clearly see they are two different things.